# getting same result with every input

Tags: python

getting same result everytime

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

raw_input("Enter a word:")
original=raw_input()

if len(original)>0 :
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

please tell the mistake and any other alternative to perform task

Comment: ...Did Python ask you enter something twice? Try `original=raw_input('Enter a word: ')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'combine' these to lines

```
raw_input("Enter a word:")
original=raw_input()
```

to a single one like this

```
original = raw_input("Enter a word: ")
```

in order to assign the word the user typed in to the variable `original`.